# Gelfand's Algebra problem number 43; dividing stick into equal pieces.

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, fractions

I have decided to study maths from scratch and am currently studying from [Algebra, I.M. Gelfand.](https://www.amazon.in/Algebra-Isarel-M-Gelfand/dp/0817636773)

The solution to this problem is already answered [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3055920/stuck-on-gelfand-algebra-problem-43-please-help)

Howsoever I was not able to understand the solution; neither from the aforementioned source, nor from the solution provided in the book itself.

The problem statement, along with the solution provided by the author is [mentioned here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLlIp.png)

Please help me to understand the proof of: -

> Why any piece (except the two pieces in the end) contains exactly 1
>   mark (which may be red and green)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously in the book, you saw that:

$$ \frac{a}{b} < \frac{a+c}{b+d} < \frac{c}{d} $$

Put the red and green marks in the first and third terms:

$$ \frac{a}{13} < \frac{a+c}{b+d} < \frac{c}{7} $$

Add their denominators and put the result into the second term $ b + d = 20 $:

$$ \frac{a}{13} < \frac{a+c}{20} < \frac{c}{7} $$

If the red marks are at distances $ \frac{1}{7}, \frac{2}{7}, \frac{3}{7}, ... $, the green marks at distances $ \frac{1}{13}, \frac{2}{13}, \frac{3}{13}, ..., $ and the cuts at $ \frac{1}{20}, \frac{2}{20}, \frac{3}{20}, ... $

Using the first equation you can assert that all the $ \frac{a+c}{20} $ pieces are between a red mark and a green mark.

For example, if take a look at the second piece which goes from $ \frac{1}{20} $ to $ \frac{2}{20} $, you can say:

$$ \frac{1}{13} < \frac{2}{20} < \frac{1}{7} $$

That means your second cut is after the first green mark and before the first red mark. In fact, any cut except the first and last, will be between marks:

$$ \frac{k}{13} < \frac{k+l}{20} < \frac{l}{7} $$